# It's a [tag:trap]!

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, clean-up

I just happened to come across [trap](/questions/tagged/trap), a wikiless tag in serious need of cleanup.

It looks like [about a third of the questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trap+bash) are about the [bash builtin command `trap`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html), with [a few more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trap+powershell) about the [equivalent command in powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847742.aspx) and [a couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trap+ruby) about [ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-trap).  A [bunch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trap+snmp) are about [SNMP traps](http://www.net-snmp.org/tutorial/tutorial-5/commands/snmptrap.html), while [the remainder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trap+-bash+-powershell+-snmp), about half of the total, are *mostly* about [CPU interrupt traps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_%28computing%29).

As far as I see, most of the questions that *don't* fall into the above groups should simply have the tag removed, and the SNMP questions might deserve to be split off to their own tag ([snmp-trap](/questions/tagged/snmp-trap)?).

However, that still leaves us the question of **what to do about the shell commands vs. the CPU interrupts?**  They *are* sort of related, but not *so* closely that they'd really fit comfortably under the same tag.  My first inclination would've been to declare [trap](/questions/tagged/trap) to be about the interrupts, since those are the more fundamental concept of the two, but then what do we do about the shell questions?  Or should we move the CPU trap questions under [interrupt](/questions/tagged/interrupt) (which is kind of in need of cleanup itself) and leave [trap](/questions/tagged/trap) for the shell commands?

---

Edit: To start with, I've simply removed the [trap](/questions/tagged/trap) tag from the following questions:

- <sup>[What techniques can be used to detect so called “black holes” (a spider trap) when creating a web crawler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512936/what-techniques-can-be-used-to-detect-so-called-black-holes-a-spider-trap-wh)</sup>
- <sup>[What's the most insidious way to pose this problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643594/whats-the-most-insidious-way-to-pose-this-problem)</sup>
- <sup>[jQuery: Trap all click events before they happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157486/jquery-trap-all-click-events-before-they-happen)</sup>
- <sup>[Determining if a point is “trapped” (enclosed) on a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768626/determining-if-a-point-is-trapped-enclosed-on-a-grid)</sup>
- <sup>[rcurl web scraping timeout exits program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867416/rcurl-web-scraping-timeout-exits-program)</sup>
- <sup>[How not to run into the intellectual property trap on a daily basis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006772/how-not-to-run-into-the-intellectual-property-trap-on-a-daily-basis)</sup>
- <sup>[A* path finding: backed into a corner, now what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684996/a-path-finding-backed-into-a-corner-now-what)</sup>
- <sup>[How do you trap when the user clicks on a ListPreference from the menu that pops up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391329/how-do-you-trap-when-the-user-clicks-on-a-listpreference-from-the-menu-that-pops)</sup>
- <sup>[How do I trap windows key, alt+tab, ctrl+alt+delete in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346689/how-do-i-trap-windows-key-alttab-ctrlaltdelete-in-c)</sup>
- <sup>[TextField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: return trap!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959083/textfieldshouldchangecharactersinrangereplacementstring-return-trap)</sup>
- <sup>[Trap errors when eval string content to a hash p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372443/trap-errors-when-eval-string-content-to-a-hash-p)</sup>
- <sup>[How can I trap the unknown cause of a Javascript popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963457/how-can-i-trap-the-unknown-cause-of-a-javascript-popup)</sup>
- <sup>[How can I trap the user in inputdlg()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841403/how-can-i-trap-the-user-in-inputdlg)</sup>
- <sup>[KeyDown/KeyPress and Indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089659/keydown-keypress-and-indexing)</sup>
- <sup>[Nutch How to avoid crawl calendar webpage generated by CGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029424/nutch-how-to-avoid-crawl-calendar-webpage-generated-by-cgi)</sup>
- <sup>[How to trap a PHP script error which dies (Perl has eval)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908925/how-to-trap-a-php-script-error-which-dies-perl-has-eval)</sup>

I think that's most of the simply misplaced ones that don't belong to any of the groups described above.

Comment: Why not just remove the trap tag from all of the questions, retagging them as appropriate?  I can't see any good use for it here.